# Migrating code from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I am trying to write a C# Version of a Server.

Both the original Client and Server were written in C++.

From my C++ Client, I can connect to the new C# Server. But since my C++ Client sends data using pointers, I am getting some trouble to read it properly.

The C++ Client sends a Char Ptr (char *pData) to my Server. This data contains a Header (that informs what kind of data I am sending, i.e.: Request Login) and a Body (with the actual data, i.e.: ID and Password).

Checking the old server, I can see it reading the data like this:

```
DWORD *dwpMsgID;
dwpMsgID = (DWORD *)(pData + DEF_INDEX4_MSGID); // define DEF_INDEX4_MSGID  0 because its the header position
switch (*dwpMsgID)
{
   ...
   case MSGID_REQUEST_LOGIN: doSomething(); // define MSGID_REQUEST_LOGIN 0x0DF3074F
   ...
}
```

After that, it then checks the Login/Password like this:

```
cp = (char *)(pData + DEF_INDEX2_MSGTYPE + 2);

memcpy(cAccountName, cp, 10);
cp += 10;
memcpy(cAccountPass, cp, 10);
cp += 10;
```

My doubt is: since I am getting a byte[] from C# Sockets, how could I check that Header to see if it matchs with "0x0DF3074F" and then get the AccountName and Password ? 
I've tryed to convert that byte[] into a String (using Encoding.Unicode.GetString() or Encoding.ASCII.GetString()) but I got no success.

Thanks in advance! Any help will be welcome at this point!
Regards

Comment: A character array in c++ ends with a '\0'.  In c# you must add the end character when sending data to c++, and you must test for the end character to determine the length of the character array when getting data from c++

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not that data is being sent using pointers, but rather that you're sending binary data. Your C# server needs to convert 4 bytes into a number.

You can use [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx) for this.

You already figured out how to process the string part of the payload.